# Messenger ref parameter is not passed to dialogflow

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to connect messenger bot and dialogflow.
The idea is - when you click on the button, service is redirecting you to the me link
(example: http://m.me/2010070995927131?ref=initial_message_with_param)
then dialoglflow receives initial_message_with_param as message and fullfilment can generate the response.

Sending messages works at all but unfortunately, ref param doesn't.
Do you have any ideas why ref param is ignored on Dialogflow side?

Comment: Based on this, I guess this is not possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529329/dialogflow-messenger-referrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been few months, but i just came across here.

Under the "Edit Page Subscription Fields" in Messaging > Webhook in Facebook developers, you need to enable **messaging_referrals** to receive referral payload calls.