# Dialogflow messenger-referrals

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to get the GET_STARTED payload with reference parameters firing to my chatbot running on a node express.js instance.

If I do a get started with refereral call with no active conversation thread, I can access the parameters no problem.

The issue is, however, if I click on a referral link with a conversation thread with my bot already open. I get no post to my fulfillment server.

I have enabled `messaging_referrals` within the facebook developer console, is there some Intent or Event I need to create within the dialogflow console to pass it to my webhook?

**For Context:**

[Messenger ref parameter is not passed to dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137302/messenger-ref-parameter-is-not-passed-to-dialogflow)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/dialogflow/oldK752j-Ok/GrwJajfwBAAJ

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_referrals#customer-chat

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links/

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, I received a reply from DialogFlow support, stating that they don't support this functionality.

Comment: I just checked and it workds as you described: 
- when no active thread, getting started sends the referal along with the FACEBOOK_WELCOME event
- when active thread, referal is not received by dialogflow